# jpa referencing foreign table instead of foreign column in JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

*App* and *History* with a `OneToMany`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class App implements Serializable {
    @Id     @Column(name = "app_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long appId;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "app", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<History> history = new HashSet<>();
    //get.set
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "app_history")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class History implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "history_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long historyId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "appId")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    private App app;
    //get.set
}
```

**Seeing in log:**

```
create table app (app_id int8 not null, name varchar(255), primary key (app_id))

create table app_history (history_id int8 not null, app_id int8, primary key (history_id))

alter table app_history add constraint FKeuk3km6r7oklj5xc1ecwvxmkm foreign key (app_id) 
references app
```

**Expecting the above line to be**

```
alter table app_history add constraint FKeuk3km6r7oklj5xc1ecwvxmkm foreign key (app_id) 
references app (app_id)
```

So, why is `(app_id)` missing when jpa is trying to create the table?

**Notes:** I'm on

- mysql v8.0.12
- mysql-connector-java v8.0.13
- spring-boot v2.1.0.RELEASE
- Full code [here](https://github.com/anandchakru/rest-repo-jpa/tree/f7f15d3c6224b8925f74396dd1d4dbfdb1c97d4c):
- Logs are [here](https://github.com/anandchakru/rest-repo-jpa/blob/master/jpa.log.txt?raw=true)

Comment: Is it possible that the line is a single line but broken up by your logger/whatever you're viewing it in? And that `references app (app_id)` follows directly behind the `alter ...` statement? Is the `references` actually not being created in your database?

Comment: oh no, the following line in the log is a big ugly exception complaining about this sql

Comment: Can you post the log? Also, what database are you using?

Comment: `alter table app_history add constraint FKeuk3km6r7oklj5xc1ecwvxmkm foreign key (app_id) 
references app` is a valid stattement in H2 database.

Comment: H2 is not in my classpath. I'm trying to connect to mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem: you are using a MySQL database, but the dialect used by JPA is for PostgreSQL:

```
spring: 
  main: 
    banner-mode: "off"
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cifi3?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: tester
    password: tester
  jpa: 
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show_sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
      format_sql: true
  data:
    rest:
      basePath: /repo
```

I suggest you to change `database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` in `database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Comment: still, no luck.. (tried with both `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` & `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect`) but still not seeing the correct querry: `Hibernate: alter table app_history add constraint FKeuk3km6r7oklj5xc1ecwvxmkm foreign key (app_id) references app (app_id)`

Comment: nvm, changing it from `@JoinColumn(name = "app_id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "appId")` fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Working as expected at [this](https://github.com/anandchakru/rest-repo-jpa/tree/168c8faecdd3ed1c597a811f93ae6c3c2eb210d9) commit.

Answer (score 2):

Change your

`@JoinColumn(name = "appId")`

to

`@JoinColumn(name = "app_id")`

This should work.

Comment: Better yet, dump all the `@Column` and `@JoinColumn` annotations unless you really need them.

Comment: changing to `@JoinColumn(name = "app_id")` didn't help. removing the annotations also didn't help.